# Chronologically list the last pages edited in order in OneNote 2019?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

Does OneNote 2019 have a way to list chronologically the last n pages edited in order?

Wiki's tend to have this feature, and I prefer wiki's to OneNote for many reasons, but employers, at least in the state I live in, tend to prefer OneNote.  However, having a history of what you did at the end of the day is really helpful and one of many reasons I prefer wiki's to OneNote.  That said though, I'm unlikely yo vhange my employers' mind, so, is there an equivalent functionality there?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into **History** menu? It is all there, especially look at the last menu item:

[image]

Also see [official documentation page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/see-a-list-of-recent-changes-in-a-notebook-in-onenote-for-windows-55dc5183-9112-4c7e-a9cf-44cd66c19c77).

---

Mobile solution: In OneNote app for Android there is a view called **Recent Pages** so you can quickly check recent edits on the go.